# Remove shadow border on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a issue on IE 9. I use the attribute:

```
 border: 2px solid #ffffff;
```

but on IE 9 it does not show properly. Another browser (Chrome, FF) is OK.

[image]

Why does the shadow appear on IE 9 ?? This is demo http://jsfiddle.net/rdqm4wns/. Please, run it on IE9

Comment: Can you provide the markup, too? I would also want to see what other styles are on the element. It looks like something is going on with the border-radius.

Comment: @PaulRedmond: this is demo http://jsfiddle.net/rdqm4wns/. pls, run it on IE9

Comment: is it wrapped in a `<a>` tag?

Comment: @Mark: No, Mark. i don't use <a> tag.  pls launch this url : jsfiddle.net/rdqm4wns for more detail (IE9 only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rendering bug causing leakage of the radius into the border width.

Add this rule will resolve it: `background-clip: padding-box;`

```
.btn-radius {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    background: #444444;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```